# Show that $U$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> "One step subspace test says: Let $V$ be a vector space and $U \subset V$ be a non-empty subset of $V$ such that
> $$\forall\vec{u},\vec{v}\in U\text{ and }\forall c\in \mathbb{R}:\vec{u}+c\vec{v}\in U$$
> Show that $U$ is a subspace of $V$."

In order to prove that the subset $U$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$, I need to show only two things

1. Show that $U$ is closed under addition.
2. Show that $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

because it is given that $U$ is non-empty. Here is my attempt at the proof:

> (1) Suppose $(\vec{u_1},\vec{v_1})$ and $(\vec{u_2},\vec{v_2})$ are in $U$, then $\vec{u_1}+c\vec{v_1}\in U$ and $\vec{u_2}+c\vec{v_2}\in U$. Additionally, $(\vec{u_1},\vec{v_1})+(\vec{u_2},\vec{v_2})=(\vec{u_1}+\vec{u_2},\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2})$, then $\vec{u_1}+\vec{u_2}+c\vec{v_1}+c\vec{v_2}=(\vec{u_1}+\vec{u_2})+c(\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2})\in U$; hence $(\vec{u_1},\vec{v_1})+(\vec{u_2},\vec{v_2})$ is still in $U$.
> (2) If $(\vec{u},\vec{v})\in U$, then for any scalar $b\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $b(\vec{u},\vec{v})=(b\vec{u},b\vec{v})$ which in turn creates $b\vec{u}+bc\vec{v}=b(\vec{u}+c\vec{v})$ which is still in $U$.
> Because properties (1) and (2) are satisfied, $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Is this correct? If so, how can I improve? If not, what am I missing?
**EDIT**: If I am understanding correctly, because we aren't given elements of the subset such as $U=\{(a,b,c)|a\geq b\}$ and because $U$ is nonempty, we have to manipulate vectors in their general form, which we suppose are in the subset, to fit the restrictions we are given in a way that still satisfies the three properties to prove a subspace.

In order to prove that the subset $U$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$, I need to show three things

1. Show that $\vec{0} \in U$.
2. Show that if $\vec{x}, \vec{y}\in U$, then $\vec{x}+\vec{y}\in U$.
3. Show that if $\vec{x}\in U$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then $a\vec{x}\in U$.

> (1) Since $U$ is given to be non-empty, let $\vec{x_0}\in U$. Since $\vec{u}+c\vec{v}\in U$, if $\vec{u}=\vec{v}=\vec{x_0}$ and $c=-1$, then $\vec{x_0}+(-1)\vec{x_0}\in U$. Hence, $\vec{0} \in U$.
> (2)If $\vec{x}, \vec{y}\in U$, let $\vec{u}=\vec{x}$, $\vec{v}=\vec{y}$, and $c=1$. Since $\vec{u}+c\vec{v}\in U$, $\vec{x}+\vec{y}\in U$.
> (3)If $\vec{x}\in U$, then let $\vec{u}=\vec{v}=\vec{x}$ and $c=a-1$. Since $\vec{u}+c\vec{v}\in U$ and $\vec{u}+c\vec{v}=\vec{x}+(a-1)\vec{x}=a\vec{x}$, it follows that $ax\in U$.
> Because properties (1), (2), and (3) are satisfied, $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Assuming that this is now the correct proof, is there any way I can improve?

Comment: In (1) you are adding ordered pairs of vectors in U, but that is not what 1. asks for. You have simply to show that adding two vectors of U gives a vector in U. To do that simply take c=1. For 2. simply take the vector u as the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of $U$ are not pairs. You have to show

1. $0\in U$
2. if $x,y\in U$, then $x+y\in U$
3. if $x\in U$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $ax\in U$

Since $U$ is not empty, let $x_0\in U$. Then $x_0+(-1)x_0\in U$ (use $u=x_0$, $v=x_0$, $c=-1$).

If $x,y\in U$, then $x+y\in U$ (use $u=x$, $v=y$, $c=1$).

If $x\in U$, then $ax=x+(a-1)x\in U$ (use $u=x$, $v=x$, $c=a-1$).

Comment: For the first part, when you're showing that $0\in U$, why do you use $x_0$ as opposed to just $x$?

Comment: @Jordan No particular reason. Just to emphasize it's a fixed element of $U$. In the other two arguments, $x$ and $y$ are “generic” elements.

Comment: I see. So it wouldn't necessarily be wrong to use $x$, but it would leave some ambiguity? Also I added my full response to your answer in my original question, as there didn't seem to be enough room here.

Comment: @Jordan You can call it whatever you like.